# How to paint bitmap data on a X11 window surface with cairo?

Tags: cairo, xlib

I want to paint bitmap data into a X11 window with cairo-xlib.

I am doing as below, but it does not work.

```
    cairo_surface_t* x11_surface;
    x11_surface = cairo_xlib_surface_create(display,
                                            xwindow,
                                            visual,
                                            width,
                                            height);
    cairo_surface_t* img_surface;
    img_surface = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data((unsigned char*)data,
                                                       CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32,
                                                       width, height, width * 4);

    cairo_t *context = cairo_create(x11_surface);

    cairo_set_source_surface(context, img_surface, 0, 0);
    cairo_set_operator(context, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
    cairo_paint(context);
    cairo_destroy(context);
```

This works:

```
    Pixmap pixmap = XCreatePixmapFromBitmapData(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), (char *) data, width, height, 0, 0, depth);
    XCopyPlane(display, pixmap, xwindow, DefaultGC(display, DefaultScreen(display)), 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);

    XFlush(display);
    XFreePixmap(display, pixmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was missing:

```
cairo_surface_destroy(x11_surface);
cairo_surface_destroy(img_surface);
```